# Domain Controller WS2008R2 and Windows10

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain, windows-10

I'd like to upgrade my five PC clients from Windows 7 to Windows 10, but I won't upgrade my server (Windows Server 2008R2).

*I will have any issues with the management of the domain?* I use very basic GPOs, like disable control panel into clients or distribute printers.

I'm sure that I will not have issues with program compatibility because all my programs runs into the server.

If you need more information on my system, just let me know!

Answer (score 0):

No, you  will not have issues.